# GridLayoutManager в RecyclerView отображает каждый ряд на новом экране, а не на одном

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Для `Recyclerview` в фрагменте использую `GridLayoutManager`.
Если две и более колонок `mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), 2)`, то каждый ряд отображает на отдельном экране (получается 7-8 экранов вниз!!), а если 1 колонку, то все нормально отображает (на одном экране). Что я делаю не так, что он на новые экраны отображает элементы?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.rv_news);
    int num_column = 2; 
    mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), num_column, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
    NewsProvider mNewsProvider = new NewsProvider();
    mAdapter = new CardAdapter(mNewsProvider.getData());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return mView;
```

Разметка элемента списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/card_image"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/card_top"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/card_image"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/card_text"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/card_image"
                android:layout_below="@+id/card_top"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Разметка фрагмента:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Tab04_NewsData.NewsFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv_news" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Разметка Активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mindzone.wireframetodemo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
         >
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</and
```

roid.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Comment: У вас же там ещё `GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false` может их убрать?..

Comment: не помогает, это я добавлял VERTICAL, потом поставил HORIZONTAL но разметка все равно вертикальная. Может еще мысли? Потому что я даже не понимаю куда копать.

Comment: А в разметке у вас что? В разметке элемента списка.